# Neo4j Import tool too many collisons

Tags: java, database, import, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to import a ~52GB file of nodes into neo4j using the import tool, I've run it twice and tried getting rid of duplicates in the file using the "uniq" Linux command on the file.

I'm running neo4j on a dedicated server

- Ubuntu Server 16.04 "Xenial Xerus" LTS
- RAM: 64GB
- Hard drive: SoftRAID 
  3x2 TB Server
- Processor: Intel Xeon E5-1620 Quad-core (4 Core) 3.60
  Ghz

> My config file settings:
>
> - dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=10G
> - dbms.memory.heap.max_size=20G
> - dbms.memory.pagecache.size=20G

The import command in using :

> neo4j-admin import --database instaGraphPostPurge.db --nodes:User "/home/headers/graph_header.csv,/home/instanet/postpurge/postUniqNodes.net"  --relationships:FOLLOWS "/home/headers/graph_relate_following.csv,/home/instanet/postpurge/following/graph1.net,/home/instanet/postpurge/following/graph2.net,/home/instanet/postpurge/following/graph3.net,/home/instanet/postpurge/following/graph4.net,/home/instanet/postpurge/following/graph5.net"  --relationships:FOLLOWS "/home/headers/graph_relate_followedBY.csv,/home/instanet/postpurge/followedBy/graph1.net,/home/instanet/postpurge/followedBy/graph2.net,/home/instanet/postpurge/followedBy/graph3.net,/home/instanet/postpurge/followedBy/graph4.net,/home/instanet/postpurge/followedBy/graph5.net" --delimiter TAB --ignore-duplicate-nodes

The node import and sort seem to finish then I get the error of

> "
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.InputException: Too many collisions: 2320721971"

I'm not too sure what the problem is, I've searched my node file for that ID but can't seem to find it.

I've included the output after the import.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

IMPORT DONE in 15h 10m 10s 79ms.
Data statistics is not available.
Peak memory usage: 18.65 GB

```
    ******** DETAILS 2018-06-15 05:17:41.913+0000 ********

    Nodes
    [*Nodes---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]2.36B
    Memory usage: 18.65 GB
    I/O throughput: 79.33 MB/s
    VM stop-the-world time: 631ms
    Duration: 47m 48s 468ms
    Done batches: 236827

    Prepare node index
    [*DETECT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]6.96B
    Memory usage: 29.67 GB
    Duration: 14h 22m 16s 475ms
    Done batches: 696830

    Environment information:
      Free physical memory: 3.32 GB
      Max VM memory: 13.99 GB
      Free VM memory: 285.40 MB
      VM stop-the-world time: 631ms
      Duration: 15h 10m 4s 943ms
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.InputException: Too many collisions: 2320721971
>           at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.AbstractStep.issuePanic(AbstractStep.java:150)
>           at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.AbstractStep.issuePanic(AbstractStep.java:142)
>           at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.LonelyProcessingStep.lambda$receive$0(LonelyProcessingStep.java:58)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.InputException: Too many collisions: 2320721971
>           at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.detectAndMarkCollisions(EncodingIdMapper.java:451)
>           at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.prepare(EncodingIdMapper.java:234)
>           at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.IdMapperPreparationStep.process(IdMapperPreparationStep.java:56)
>           at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.LonelyProcessingStep.lambda$receive$0(LonelyProcessingStep.java:53)
>           ... 1 more
>   Error in input data
>   Caused by:Too many collisions: 2320721971
>
> WARNING Import failed. The store files in /home/databases/instaGraphPostPurge.db are left as they are, although they are likely in an unusable state. Starting a database on these store files will likely fail or observe inconsistent records so start at your own risk or delete the store manually
>   org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.InputException: Too many collisions: 2320721971
>           at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.detectAndMarkCollisions(EncodingIdMapper.java:451)
>           at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.prepare(EncodingIdMapper.java:234)
>           at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.IdMapperPreparationStep.process(IdMapperPreparationStep.java:56)
>           at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.LonelyProcessingStep.lambda$receive$0(LonelyProcessingStep.java:53)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   unexpected error: Too many collisions: 2320721971

Comment: For your information: huge import time:  15h 10m ! If it's a graph db initialization another solution is available by using BatchInserter, it works directly with the DB files and very fast. But you need to code a bit in Java. Here http://www.javased.com/index.php?api=org.neo4j.kernel.impl.batchinsert.BatchInserter some examples (but I don't know if these examples are based on recent version of Neo4j)

Comment: can you share your headers and perhaps first few lines of each file?

Comment: and the full output of the import command

Comment: can you combine those two follows relationships, I was not aware that oyu can have multiple of the same type on the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Too many collisions: 2320721971` tells you that the number of collisions is `2320721971`, which is too many for the importer to handle. Now that isn't actually true any more in 3.4, where there have been collision management improvements, and so that limit is gone but the importer still makes this check for some reason.

Now, this could be fixed, but > 2.3 billion collisions is quite a lot of collisions and points to some really dirty or not-quite-cleaned-up input data. Removing this check would make it work, but the amount of memory to store those collisions could be overwhelming too, so the import might still fail when trying to allocate that memory anyway.

The best you can do is to reduce the number of duplicate node IDs in your input somehow.

Comment: I ended up having to remove more of the duplicates, my data ended up not being in the format I though it was and had to sort then remove the duplicates. Thanks for the help